# Why cant I add an array as a member to my object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For my express/mongo/mongoose router Im trying to append a object to another object before I send it. Unfortunately it never does. Where am I mistaken?

Worth noting response_study is an array of objects, if that matters.

Also the response_study is not null.

```
apiRouter.route('/compounds/:_id')

    .get(function(req, res) {
        Compound.findById(req.params._id, function(err, compound) {
            if (err) res.send(err);

            Study.find({compound_id: compound._id}, function( err, response_study){
               if (err) res.send(err);

               compound["studies"] = response_study;
               console.log(compound);  //logs compound without studies parameter

               res.json(compound);
           });
       });
   })
```

Comment: Where is `compound` defined? Also you should `return` on errors, else you are still executing the following code. Like `if(err) return res.send(err);`

Comment: @migg you should `return` before any `res` statement that responds back to the requester

Comment: @peteb not neccessarily, I could still want to update something in the background. But you are right that most of the time this will be the right approach.

Comment: @migg compound is returned in the  `Compound.findByID()` promise. Also thanks for the heads up. Will change in code.

Comment: Try `compound.studies = response_study`.

Comment: @migg yep that was my first unsuccessful method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Mongoose? If so they don't return plain objects but `MongooseDocument` objects. You need to convert the `MongooseDocument` to a plain object before you alter it or your changes won't have any effect:

```
var response = compound.toObject();
response.studies = response_study;
res.json(response);
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

It's been a while since I used mongoose, so it might be `toJSON` instead

Comment: Thanks Rob, I had feeling it was some mongoose / express jumble. Your code worked verbatim. `res.json` was fine

Comment: I was questioning everything I new about JS objects. Feel better now